# Как создать всплывающее окно (popup) в моём собственном окне, используя dcef3?

Tags: delphi, popup, tab

Привет всем! Я бы хотел создать новое всплывающее окно в своем собственном окне. Для чего это? Я хочу, чтобы всплывающее окно открывалось в моем собственном, потому что я использую вкладки, и хотел бы ограничить всплывающее окно. В качестве примера можно взять сайт https://badoo.com/ru/signin/, зайдя на который и кликнув по кнопке "Вконтакте" или "Facebook", будет создано новое всплывающее окно. Я пробовал решить данную проблему через событие `BeforePopup`, но безрезультатно. Код примера:

```
     myHandle:HWND;
...
  myHandle:= findwindow(nil, 'Wrapper');
...
procedure TChromium_wrapper.BeforePopup(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const frame: ICefFrame; const targetUrl,
  targetFrameName: ustring; var popupFeatures: TCefPopupFeatures;
  var windowInfo: TCefWindowInfo; var client: ICefClient;
  var settings: TCefBrowserSettings; var noJavascriptAccess: Boolean;
  out Result: Boolean);
begin
  windowInfo.window := myHandle;
end;
```

Я не могу создать новый браузер, потому что данное всплывающее окно связано с текущим браузером. Может ли мне кто-то помочь?